# rCharts - Adding second y axis to dimple

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

Is it possible in dimple within rCharts to create a chart with secondary y axis. I want to create something as below where line belongs to the y2 axis.

[image: dimple rCharts secondary axis]

And if not dimple then any other ***open source*** library in rCharts?

Comment: rCharts is being reimplemented as an `htmlwidget`.  See if https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rcdimple/issues/20 helps and let me know.

Comment: Yes that was helpful. Thank you.